# Array with hex values in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, hex

For the last day I have had some problems with this code. Here I want to upload with a .txt several hexadecimal values and if the sum of the first five numbers is equal to the last number, the code is correct.Then, the method main have to check if the rest methods were succeeded. But I don't know how do this, so I need your help...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define FILECODE  "file.txt"
#define N_CODE 6

using namespace std;

ifstream file;

void uploadCode(bool& exist, unsigned int longCode, unsigned int code[]);
bool IsValidCode(unsigned int code[]);

void main() {
    unsigned int code[N_CODE];
    bool exist;
    unsigned int longCode=N_CODE;
    IsValidCode(code);
    if(IsValidCode(code)==true){
        uploadCode(exist,longCode,code); //here I have the problem because I don't know how to call the method
        cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "FAIL" << endl;

}

void uploadCode(bool& exist, unsigned int longCode, unsigned int code[]) {
    int i;
    file.open(FILECODE);
    if(file){
        exist=true;
        for(int i=0;i<longCode;i++){
            file >> hex >> code[i];
            cout << "Number " << i << ":  "<< code[i] << endl;
        }

        cout << "EXIST" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "NO EXIST" << endl;
        exist=false;
    file.close();

}

bool IsValidCode(unsigned int code[]) {
    int i;
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<N_CODE-1; i++)
        sum+=code[i];
        cout << "Sum first five numbers:  " << sum << endl;
    if(sum==code[6])
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: This is a good example of naming for why not to needlessly use macros. `FILE` is used in the standard library.

Comment: In `IsValidCode()` `return sum;` will never be executed.

Comment: @chris *This is a good example of naming for why not to needlessly use macros* I had to read that 3 times before I understood what you meant

Comment: What is `IsValid(code);`?  Also, you are calling `IsValidCode(code);` on an uninitialized array -- so that function is just examining whatever garbage happens to be on the stack.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: @chris Sorry, that's because some words of this code were in spanish and I translated them, like `FILE´. I already changed it.

Comment: @Borgleader, Sorry, it was going to not include the naming part, but it's not actually screwing with anything here, so it's not a very good general example.

Comment: In `uploadCode` I don't think `if (file)` is legal and you always set `exist` to `false` before you return.

Comment: @jschultz410 how I can initialize array here? I am a rookie programming with C++ and I don't understand some things...

Comment: @MissPaper: You could initialize them to zero like so: `unsigned int code[N_CODE] = { 0 };` but then `IsValidCode` (which you call twice for no reason) will always return false.  So, you probably want to set the values in `code` to something you actually want to test and potentially output.  Maybe you mean to call `uploadCode` (strange name, btw) first and then test if the contents of the file with `IsValidCode`?

Comment: The last line in `IsValidCode` should be `return sum == code[6];`. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @jschultz410 Yes, I want to call **uploadCode** in **IsValidCode** adding values from file.txt into array and check if the sum is right. How can I do that?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Actually, it should `return sum == code[5];` or `return sum == code[NCODE-1];` as there is no valid index 6 for that array.  Also, declaring `i` at the function scope and again inside a loop scope in that function is begging for a bug.

Answer (score 0):

In your `main` function, you are calling `IsValidCode` twice before the data is read from the file.  I don't think this is what you want.

A preferred method is:

- Read first 6 numbers.
- Sum the first 5 numbers.
- If the sum != 6th number, return error status from `main()`.

You don't need to make separate functions for each item above.  Put them all in the `main` function.  *(The overhead to call and return from the simple functions may be more code than contained in the function.)*

**Edit 1:  An example**

```
int main(void)
{
  const unsigned int CODE_LENGTH = 6;
  ifstream input_file("file.txt");
  if (!input_file)
  {
    cerr << "Error opening file.txt\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  unsigned int sum = 0;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i > CODE_LENGTH - 1; ++i)
  {
    unsigned int value = 0;
    input_file >> hex >> value;
    sum += value;
  }
  unsigned int expected_sum = 0;
  input_file >> hex >> expected_sum;
  if (sum != expected_sum)
  {
    cerr << "sum != expected sum.\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  // ....
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Simple, no arrays necessary, no additional functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimally modified version that does what you want.  Of course, much better checks should be done on the return values of your input processing (i.e. - `file >> hex >> code[i];`) to see if those inputs are actually succeeding or not.

```
bool uploadCode(unsigned int longCode, unsigned int code[]) 
{
    bool ret;

    file.open(FILECODE);  // TODO: no need for a global here; just use a locally constructed ifstream

    if (file.good())
    {
        ret = true;

        for(int i = 0; i < longCode; ++i)
        {
            file >> hex >> code[i];
            cout << "Number " << i << ":  "<< code[i] << endl;
        }

        cout << "EXIST" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        ret = false;
        cout << "NO EXIST" << endl;
    }

    file.close();

    return ret;
}

int main() 
{
    unsigned int code[N_CODE];

    if (!uploadCode(N_CODE, code))
    {
      cout << "File failure!" << endl;
      return 1;
    }

    if (!IsValidCode(code))
    {
        cout << "Code failure!" << endl;
        return 2;
    }

    cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```